# getting an error when try to pass the messege to client

Tags: python

sir, i am developing an server client appication using python. but when i run the server it just works fine and when i run the client, in the server i am getting an error saying

conn.sendall(reply)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'tuple'

it seems like server cannot reply the messege to client. but i have no idea how to solve it. please anyone help me... here is my server code:

```
import socket
import sys

HOST = '127.0.0.1';   # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 2014; # Arbitrary non-privileged port

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print ("Socket created")
print ("Socket bind complete")
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(10) 
print ("Socket now listening")

#now keep talking with the client
while True:
#wait to accept a connection - blocking call
conn, addr = s.accept()
print ("Connected with ", addr[0] ,":" , str(addr[1]))

data = conn.recv(1024)
reply = ("O", data)
if not data: 
    break

conn.sendall(reply)// here it comes the error, i have used encode.('utf-8') but no luck

conn.close()
s.close()
```

Comment: `reply` is a tuple. But you can't call `sendall` using a tuple. Try making `reply` something else. Perhaps a bytes object, or something like a bytes object.

Comment: You are trying to send the tuple `("0", data)` with the `.sendall()` method. This method requires a `bytes`-like object instead. What are you trying to accomplish with the `"0"` prefix?

Comment: sir, what type of thing? l have used sendto, but that doesnt work

Comment: Sir, i want to send just a reply saying O or what ever to client when a messege is recieved from client

Comment: then, for a simple start, just return what was sent: `conn.sendall(data)`.